# How to Draw an 2d Array

Tags: python, matplotlib

How could I graph this array `u`,

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi=np.arccos(-1)
#Parameters En la ecuación del calor 1D
L = 1.;
T =1.; 

#Parámetros del método
maxk = 2500; # Divisiones temporales
dt = T/maxk;
n = 50; # Divisiones espaciales
dx = L/n;
cond = 1/4; # Conductividad
b = 2.*cond*dt/(dx*dx); # Alpha

u=[[None]*maxk]*n
x=[None]*n
time=[None]*maxk
# Suponga temperatura distribuida de forma senoidal en la varilla para t=0
for i in range(0,n):
  x[i] =i*dx;
  u[i][0] =np.sin( pi*x[i] );

# Suponga una frontera a temperatura cero
for k in range(0,maxk):
  u[0][k] = 0.;
  u[n-1][k] = 0.;
  time[k] = k*dt;

#Metodo explicito de solucion
for k in range(0,maxk-1):
  for i in range(1, n-2):
   u[i][k+1] =u[i][k] + 0.5*b*u[i-1][k]+u[i+1][k]-2.*u[i][k];
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 13.2))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('colorMap')
plt.imshow(u)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

cax = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.8])
cax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
cax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
cax.patch.set_alpha(0)
cax.set_frame_on(False)
plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

I would expect a result like this

[image: good example]

but I get something like this
[image: another bad]
[image: bad example]

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, but don't use `;` at the end of python code.

Comment: Also, I would recommend making `u` and `x` numpy arrays and using vectorized operations.

Comment: Your array `u` only contains zeros. Also, it is 50 high and 2500 long, which is the green bar in the center of the plot.  You could make it more rectangular by setting `set_aspect('auto')`.  The 5 lines mentioning `cax` doesn't seem to do anything useful. Better leave them out.